# Proving a product over the primes is non-zero.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove some results on finding sequences of square-free numbers, and the following product shows as a probability (P is the set of all primes)
$$\prod_{p \in P}\left(1 - \frac{n}{p^4}\right)$$
Where $n$ is any number, this is trivially between $0$ and $1$, and written as a sum:
$$1-\sum_{p} \frac{n}{p^4} + \sum_{p,q} \frac{n^2}{(pq)^4} - \cdots$$
Since every series in this is gonna converge, I can do the following manipulation:
$$1-n\delta + \sum_{p}\left(\frac{n}{p^4}\sum_{q}\frac{n}{q^4}\right) - \cdots$$
Which in the end allows me to write it as $(1-n\delta+n\delta^2-n\delta^3+\cdots)$ where $\delta = \zeta_P(4) = \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^4}$, but this series does not converge for large enough $n$... How does one show that the product is non-zero?

Comment: When $ n = 2^4$, won't the product be 0?

Comment: Indeed it will, back to the drawing board, thanks.